# show that $\lambda\left(\left(a,\infty\right)\right)=\infty$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Condsider the measure space $\left(\mathbb R, \mathcal B\left(\mathbb R\right), \lambda\right)$, where $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure.

Show that for every $a$ in $\mathbb R$, we have that
$$\lambda\left(\left(a, \infty\right)\right)=\infty$$

**My solution:**

I know that we have the following identity:
$$\left(a, b\right)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}\right]$$
then taking the measure of that we get:
$$\lambda\left(\left(a,\infty\right)\right)=\lambda\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left[a+\frac{1}{n},\infty\right]\right)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left(\lambda\left[a+\frac{1}{n},\infty\right]\right)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left(\infty-a-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$=\left(\infty-a-1\right)\cup\left(\infty-a-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cup \ ... \ \cup\left(\infty-a-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\infty$$
And we are done.

I don't know if this i correct, if someone could agree or disagree, I will appreciate it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You aren't working in the extended reals for your points, just your measure,  so you can't use $\infty$ as a CLOSED endpoint in your intervals,  nor can you subtract with it

Comment: Can't you assume that $\exists a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda(a,\infty) < \infty$, so $\infty - a < \infty$ and hence contradiction?

Comment: You can maybe use $(a,\infty)\supseteq(a,n)\implies\mu((a,\infty))\ge\mu((a,n))=n-a$ for every $n\ge a$…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you take as known that $\lambda([a,b])=b-a$, whenever $a < b$ are both in $\Bbb R$? (and also for half open and open intervals).

Then for any $n \in \Bbb N^+$, $[a+1, a+n+1] \subseteq (a,\infty)$ and by monotonicity of a measure we thus have $n = (a+n+1)-(a+1)= \lambda([a+1, a+n+1]) \le \lambda((a,\infty)$, so that the latter measure has no finite upper bound and must be $\infty$. You're not just allowed to take $\infty$ as a number and do subtractions just like that, but you can use monotonicity and continuity of measure, e.g. in $$\lambda((a,\infty)) = \lambda(\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty (a+n, a+n+1]) =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1 = \infty$$ where the latter is valid identity in the extended reals.